# Angularjs Material Datepicker is not working when i am trying to use it with ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-material

I am trying to use **angular material datepicker** with **ng-switch**, which i have given to a radio buttons based on the radio option date picker should load. But it is not working as expected.

This is how my code looks like.

Radio buttons

```
<div class = "row radio">
            <md-radio-group ng-model="data.group1">

              <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" ng-model="myVar" value="OneWay">One-way</md-radio-button>
              <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" ng-model="myVar" value="RoundTrip">Round Trip </md-radio-button>
              <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" ng-model="myVar" value="MultyWay">Multi-Way + Hotal</md-radio-button>

            </md-radio-group>
        </div>
```

Date picker

```
    <div class = "row Date" ng-switch="myVar">
    <div class = "col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-6" ng-switch-default>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Depart on</label>
            <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate"></md-datepicker>
          </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-10" ng-switch-when="RoundTrip">
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Depart on</label>
            <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate"></md-datepicker>
          </md-input-container>

          <md-input-container>
            <label>Return on</label>
            <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionReturnDate"></md-datepicker>
          </md-input-container>
    </div>
    </div>
```

when i click on one way it should show the single datepicker and if i select Round trip it should show the roundtrip block.

Hope there is no js required for this functionality?

May i know what is wrong hear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model="myVar"` needs to be on the `md-radio-group` element - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/EgQbPb?editors=1010)

Also, if you look in the console there is an error regarding putting `md-datepicker` within an `md-input-container` element.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div>
    <md-radio-group ng-model="myVar">
      <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" value="OneWay">One-way</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" value="RoundTrip">Round Trip </md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button  class="md-primary fix-width" value="MultyWay">Multi-Way + Hotal</md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
  </div>

  <div ng-switch="myVar">
    <div ng-switch-default>
      <div layout="column">
        <label>Depart on</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate"></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="RoundTrip">
      <div layout="column">
        <label>Round trip</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate"></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="MultyWay">
      <div layout="column">
        <label>Multi way</label>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionReturnDate"></md-datepicker>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```